Removing ns2 and xmlns from xml output when marshalling with JAXB
In java i'm doing the following conversion:
json -> POJO with Jackson
POJO -> xml with JAXB
The problem I encounter when validating the xml based upon xsd's is it throws an error because of the presence of ns2 and xmlns:ns2, like so <ns2:X001 xmlns:ns2="http://ec.europa.eu/eessi/ns/4_2/X001">.
I only need X001.
One thing to note is that I have no control over the POJO creation, because the generating of these objects is being done based upon other xsd's. These xsd's shouldn't be changed.
I would like to know if it's possible to change the bindings.xjb file to accomplish this and how or is there a different approach to this?
Altering xml string after validation but this isn't desirable.
